# Custom MKAnnotation button

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'd like to generate a custom annotation using `MKAnnotation`.
[image: imgA]

```
annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "annotation)") // this is to set the annotation image
annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "mySymbol")) // this is to add a icon left to the annotation UI
```

The few lines above are working quiet well but ... now I'd like to add a custom button to the Annotation like in the image above.

---

Using the default one is working so far :

```
annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
```

... but using a custom one is not (Just not showing a UI element, there is still **NOTHING**):

```
let myButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "myButton"), for: .normal)
annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = myButton
```

---

I have no clue how to go on... I hope somebody is able to fix this small problem.

Thanks in advance, jonas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the question asker :-)

I found a solution on my own **without creating a complete new view** - like @Sh_Khan mentioned - because this is still not necessary.

This is what I came up with:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.setImage(UIImage(named :"myIcon")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
```

Comment: I think I missed the part of the code from above. Edited @matt

Comment: Okay, so the difference is merely that in your original code you were adding a button with zero size.

Comment: Yeah. Your absolutely right. The `button.frame` property must be set.