# How to turn an MKannotation into a UI button which connects to a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation

I am new to coding and I am needing to turn an annotation into a `UIButton`. My goal is for users to click the button and it segues to another UIView similar to **Google Maps** or **Apple Maps**.

How would I be able to code the button so when clicked it displays a UIView?

Here is what I have so far:

```
func displayCordinates() {
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let storageRef = ref.child("waterfountains")

        storageRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let annotation = CustomPointAnnotation()
                let dict = child.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
                annotation.title = "Water Fountain"
                annotation.tag = dict["url"]
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: dict["lat"] as! Double, longitude: dict["long"] as! Double)

                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

                let reuseId = "pin"

                var pinView = self.mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
                var rightCalloutAccessoryView: UIView!
                if pinView == nil {
                    pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
                    pinView!.canShowCallout = true

                    pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure) as UIButton
                }
                else {
                    pinView!.annotation = annotation

                }
                }
        })

    }




func mapView(MapView: MKMapView!, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toUploadScreen", sender: self)
        print("Going to the next VC!")
    }
}
```

`

After it performed the segue it is supposed to print "Going to the next VC" yet it is not printing so something in the code must be broken and i cannot figure out what.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1616211-mapview or https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452393-mapview should help you

Comment: if your requirement is to click and move please use the below https://stackoverflow.com/a/48722685/1142743 you can refer image in the question for your requirement and use previous comment methods to detect click and navigate

Comment: how you connected toUploadScreen segue to current view